# How to show instance attributes in sphinx doc?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Is there any way to automatically show variables **var1** and **var2** and their init-values in sphinx documentation?

```
class MyClass:
    """    
    Description for class
    """

    def __init__(self, par1, par2):
       self.var1 = par1 * 2
       self.var2 = par2 * 2

    def method(self):
       pass
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Your variables are instance variables, not class variables.

Without attaching a docstring (or a `#:` "doc comment") to the variables, they won't be documented. You could do as follows:

```
class MyClass(object):
    """    
    Description for class 

    """

    def __init__(self, par1, par2):
        self.var1 = par1 #: initial value: par1
        self.var2 = par2 #: initial value: par2

    def method(self):
        pass
```

But I would prefer to include variable documentation by using [info fields](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/domains.html#info-field-lists):

```
class MyClass(object):
    """    
    Description for class

    :ivar var1: initial value: par1
    :ivar var2: initial value: par2
    """

    def __init__(self, par1, par2):
        self.var1 = par1 
        self.var2 = par2 

    def method(self):
        pass
```

See also:

- http://www.sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html#directive-autoattribute
- [How can I make Python/Sphinx document object attributes only declared in __init__?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3959615/407651)
- [Problems with autodoc and explicitly specified instance attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17610807/407651)

Comment: Any setting required for #: doc comment to be visible in html pages by sphinx? I used sphinx-apidoc command to generate .rst files.

Comment: @varunsinghal: is there a problem?

Comment: I was using these doc comments #: for private class variables.

Comment: @varunsinghal: Perhaps you have been hit by this bug? https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1362

Comment: Nice answer! You do not need to use `:ivar foo:` though, just `:var foo` will do.

Comment: @RayLuo They're not synonyms though - `ivar` = instance variable, `cvar` = class variable, `var` = work it out yourself. While Sphinx doesn't care it informs a human reader.

Answer (score 0):

**`#:` doc comments: you can also put doc comments right above variables**

Besides the `self.var1 = par1 # Doc for var1` syntax you can also:

main.py

```
class MyOtherClass:
    """
    This class does that.
    """
    pass

class MyClass:
    """
    Description for class.
    """

    #: Syntax also works for class variables.
    class_var: int = 1

    def __init__(self, par1: int, par2: MyOtherClass):
        #: Doc for var1
        self.var1: int = par1

        #: Doc for var2.
        #: Another line!
        self.var2: MyOtherClass = par2

    def method(self):
        """
        My favorite method.
        """
        pass

    @classmethod
    def cmethod():
        """
        My favorite class method.
        """
        pass
```

build.sh

```
sphinx-build . out
```

conf.py

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
extensions = [ 'sphinx.ext.autodoc' ]
autodoc_default_options = {
    'members': True,
}
autodoc_typehints = "description"
```

index.rst

```
.. automodule:: main
```

requirements.txt

```
Sphinx==6.1.3
```

After `./build.sh` the output under `out/index.html` looks like:

[image]

The `#:` syntax is documented at: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autoproperty

**Using `:ivar:` and `:cvar:` instead**

There are currently tradeoffs between both methods, it is a shame that there isn't one clearly superior method.

Downsides:

- you have to type the attribute names again
- types are gone, TODO link to feature request

Upsides:

- the "Variables:` grouping looks cleaner, TODO link to feature request

Both could be better:

- clearly show that `class_var` is a class variable? TODO link to feature reuqest

```
class MyClass:
    """
    Description for class.

    :ivar var1: Doc for var1
    :ivar var2: Doc for var2.
      Another line!
    :cvar class_var: Syntax also works for class variables.
    """

    class_var: int

    def __init__(self, par1: int, par2: MyOtherClass):
        self.var1: int = par1

        self.var2: MyOtherClass = par2

    def method(self):
        """
        My favorite method.
        """
        pass

    @classmethod
    def cmethod():
        """
        My favorite class method.
        """
        pass
```

produces:

[image]

Related: [What is the difference between var, cvar and ivar in python's sphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052221/what-is-the-difference-between-var-cvar-and-ivar-in-pythons-sphinx)

Tested on Python 3.10, Ubuntu 22.10.