# How do I document "sub-classes" using sphinx and autodoc?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Assuming I have a file example.py with the following contents:

```
class Body(object):
    """Representation of a geometric body."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.surface = Surface(self)

class Surface(object):
    """Representation of a geometric surface."""
    def __init__(self, body):
        self.body = body

    def get_surface_area(self):
        """ Calculate surface area of the body """
        print 4

mybody = Body()
mybody.surface.get_surface_area()
```

When I do

```
.. automodule:: example
    :members:
```

I get all the two classes and the function documented. However, how would I go about pointing out the intended usage of my class, i.e. `mybody.surface.get_surface_area()` and also have the correct links in place?

Comment: Your code contains two classes. There are no subclasses and no functions. Please clarify.

Comment: Well, the every body has a surface connected to it, i.e. there are no surfaces without bodies. Thats why there are quotation marks around the subclass; I didn't know what to call it. And there is a method called `get_surface_area`?!

Comment: OK, a Body object holds a reference to a Surface object. And when you say function, you mean method. But I still don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: If you want to document the instance variables, then this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8659919/407651.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. Now I can at least say `:ivar surface: interface for :class:`example.Surface` and have a link to the class. Still unsure if it is clear to the reader that you can do `mybody.surface.get_surface_area()` instead of `mysurface = Surface(mybody); mysurface.get_surface_area()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if this is what you want, but here is a suggestion on how you could document your classes:

```
class Body(object):
    """Representation of a geometric body.

      :ivar surface: a :class:`example.Surface` instance 

      Usage example:

      >>> mybody = Body()
      >>> mybody.surface.get_surface_area()
      >>> 4

      Another way of doing it:

      >>> mybody = Body()
      >>> mysurface = Surface(mybody)
      >>> mysurface.get_surface_area()
      >>> 4

    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.surface = Surface(self)  

class Surface(object):
    """Representation of a geometric surface.

     :ivar body: The supplied :class:`example.Body` instance

    """
    def __init__(self, body):
        self.body = body             

    def get_surface_area(self):
        """ Calculate surface area of the body """
        print 4
```

Comment: That's probably what I'm going to do. Thank you for taking the time!