# Should Sphinx be able to document instance attributes in a class?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm finding conflicting and often dated information so hoping someone can clear this up.

I'd like to document something like this using Sphinx:

```
class MyClass:
    """
    MyClass, which is documented with a docstring at the class level
    """
    classVar = None
    """A class var with an initial value and a 1-line doc"""

    def __init__(self):
        """
        __init__'s docs
        """
        instanceVar1 = 10
        """An instance var with an initial val and 1-line doc"""

        #: An instance var with an initial val and a doc-comment
        instanceVar2 = 10
```

In my docs, I'd like to see instanceVar1 and its docstring (ideally with its default value, but I'd be happy with just the description).  But if I run with an rst file of:

```
.. automodule:: mymodule.mycode
   :members:
```

I only see the class attributes, not the instance attributes:
[image: Image showing docs]

Googling gives me conflicting info on what should/shouldn't work.  Several older stack overflow chains cite issues with autodocumentation for instance attributes (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649105/how-to-show-instance-attributes-in-sphinx-doc)) but they also refer to it working if you've added docstrings like I've done above.  Sphinx docs cite that [all attributes can be autodocumented](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autoattribute).

Can anyone comment on whether what I'm trying to do should work/it works for them now you/suggestions on what I might have messed up?  Thanks.

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but isn't this the format described [here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autoattribute) for bar, baz, quz, and spam? <-- response to a comment that is no longer here - deleted?

Comment: Automodule will only use docstrings, do you actually use autoattribute? FWIW I generally use http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html for more human-readable source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you did *should* work, and it — eventually — worked for me.

To demonstrate, I'm using the example from the Sphinx docs that you cited:

```
class Foo:
    """Docstring for class Foo."""

    #: Doc comment for class attribute Foo.bar.
    #: It can have multiple lines.
    bar = 1

    flox = 1.5   #: Doc comment for Foo.flox. One line only.

    baz = 2
    """Docstring for class attribute Foo.baz."""

    def __init__(self):
        #: Doc comment for instance attribute qux.
        self.qux = 3

        self.spam = 4
        """Docstring for instance attribute spam."""
```

I saved that as `module.py` and created the following `index.rst`:

```
.. automodule:: module
```

Along with this Sphinx configuration file, `conf.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '.')
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc']
autodoc_default_options = {
    'members':         True,
    'member-order':    'bysource',
    'special-members': '__init__',
}
```

With all three files stored in the same folder, I ran Sphinx (2.1.1) via `sphinx-build . ./html` (on Python 3.7.3 and Windows 10) to render it as HTML:
[image: rendered HTML]

As to what you "might have messed up"… Um, that's adequately put, as I'm sure you'll agree. ;-) It took me quite a while to realize this when, at first, I tried the same as above, but with the code example you provided: Your two alleged instance attributes, `instanceVar1` and `instanceVar2`, are missing the `self` identifier in front. Oops. That's why it didn't work.

Comment: oh god that's embarrassing.  No wonder I was pulling my hair out yesterday.  I started with a real package (which actually used self...) where instance variables weren't doccing right, so I dumbed it down to the above example to troubleshoot.  Turns out I accidentally added a mistake that replicates the same thing I was trying to troubleshoot! Haven't actually fixed my real module yet, but this gives me a working example!